# How to get RAW IMU data from the Google Glass?

Tags: linux-device-driver, google-glass, mpu, iio

I am trying to get RAW acceleration and gyroscope data from the Google Glass IMU module.
I tried aSensormanager module in the NDK, but it sometimes gives output with some wierd bias adjustment. So I tried to read from the driver's virtual file-system.

- When I try to read in one-shot mode from `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/`, I am getting the raw data, but sometimes it misses some data (compared to the sensor manager output).
- When I try to read in burst mode from `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/`, it shows "**/dev/iio:device0: Device or resource busy**"

So, is there any alternative way to read the raw data without losing any data, or can I configure the sensor manager to give raw data without any bias adjustment?